# Проблема с доступом к "VPN-серверу"

Tags: tcp, vpn, mikrotik, l2tp, xl2tp

Есть сервер `l2tp+ipsec` на `Raspbian`, который стоит за `microtic`, который настроен как `Access Point`. После проброса портов из вне, к VPN-серверу нет доступа.

[image: Здесь описание правил NAT]

[image: Здесь описание правил фильтров]

Как видно из правил - есть помимо всего проброс соединения `RDP` - работает без каких либо проблем. Точно так же настроенные правила для "UDP портов" 1701, 4500, 500(а позже на всякий случай и "TCP"), не принесли результата. Далее были добавлены правила фильтрации, но что с ними, что без них результата не было. Внутри локальной сети все подключается без проблем. В настройках `l2tp` не указан пул адресов с которых можно к нему подключаться - как я понимаю это позволяет подключаться с любых адресов.

Что я упускаю?

Answer (score 1):

Если присутствует 1 eth0 и ppp, то нужно настроить пересылку (что бы был интернет по VPN)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

- Для PPTP: протокол 47 и TCP-порт 1723.
- Для L2TP: протокол 50 и UDP-порт 500.